# UIAlertView textfield not accepting other language characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uialertview

In my iPad application, there is an alertview of following style UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput. The problem is I'm unable to enter any other language characters(å,ß,Ω) in alertview textfield. It's simply showing blank string in textfield after entering other language character.

```
    saveAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please provide a name for your design." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK",@"Cancel",nil];
    [saveAlert setTag:SAVE_HTML_NAME_ALERT_TAG];
    [saveAlert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
    [saveAlert show];

    alertTextField = [saveAlert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    alertTextField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15.0f];
    [alertTextField setTag:SAVE_ALERT_TEXT_FIELD_TAG];
    [alertTextField setDelegate:self];
```

Other normal textfields are working fine in application, properly displaying other language characters. There's only problem with alertview's textfield.